# Discretization of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, wiener

The Wiener process $(W_t)$ is a continuous stochastic process that satisfies the following there conditions:

1. $W_0 = 0$,
2. the increments $\mathrm{d}W_t = W_{t + \mathrm{d}t} - W_t$ are normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\mathrm{d}t$,
3. the increments are mutually independents, i.e. $\mathrm{d}W_i$ is independent from $\mathrm{d}W_j$ for every $i$ different from $j$.

I now want to discretize the Wiener process in order to simulate it as described in the beginning of “[An algorithmic introduction to numerical simulatiom of stochastic differential equation](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144500378302)” by Higham (2001).

- First, I have to discretize the time interval $[0,T]$ in $N$ sub-intervals of equal length $\delta_t = \frac{T}{N}$. In this way, each of the $N+1$ time instants are given by $t_i = i \cdot \delta_t$.
- Then, at each time instant $t_i$, the discretized version of the Wiener process is
  \begin{align*}
  W_i = W_{i-1} + \mathrm{d}W_{i-1},
  \end{align*}
  where $\mathrm{d} W_{i-1}\sim N(0,\delta_t)$ and $W_0=0$.

I would like to undestand how proprieties 2 and 3 imply the above iteration formula.

Comment: I dont know the derivation of the continuation stochastic process but I would venture that it came from this process in reverse. That is, a discrete model was developed as you stated and then the limit was evaluated as delta t goes to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what is meant is that the increment of the brownian between discrete points $(i-1)$ and $i$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance equal to $\delta t$ which represents the length of the interval between the two discrete points. You can then write the increment as $\sqrt{\delta t}$ times a standard normal random. So the equation is to be read in conjunction with the statement following the equation.

[image]

To see it more clearly, let's represent the standard normal by Z so $Z \sim N\left(0,1\right)$ and the claim is that $dW_j \sim \sqrt{\delta t} Z$. A linear transformation of a normal is normal, so $\sqrt{\delta t} Z$ is indeed normal, and its mean and variance are easy to calculate:

$E \left[\sqrt{\delta t} Z \right]=\sqrt{\delta t}E \left[Z\right]=0$

$V \left[\sqrt{\delta t} Z \right]=\delta t V \left[Z\right]=\delta t$

And because $dW_j$ has the same properties, we can say $dW_j \sim \sqrt{\delta t} Z$.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what you meant because I still not get it!

Comment: thanks. Have added further detail, hope it is clearer now, but please do let me know if any part of the explanation is not clear!

Comment: thanks for having added further details! What you added is clear. It's certainly true that dW_j is a normal random variable with mean 0 and variance dt. What is not clear to me why you can write the recursive algorithm given the proprieties 2 and 3, so for example, where the indepedence of the increments enter in the statement?

Comment: Properties 2 and 3 are needed for the central limit theorem to assert normality: "The central limit theorem states that the sum of a number of independent and identically distributed random variables with finite variances will tend to a normal distribution as the number of variables grows. " from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: If the increments were not independent, then the increments in the j-th interval could depend on the increments in the other intervals, which is going to complicate things, but only slightly - please check out the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process as an example.