# Simulation of Geometric Brownian Motion in R

Tags: programming, numerical-methods, sde, geometric-brownian

Using R, I would like to simulate a sample path of a geometric Brownian motion using

\begin{equation*}
S(t) = S(0) \exp\left(\left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)t + \sigma B_{t}\right),
\end{equation*}

where $(B_t)$ is the Wiener process, i.e. $B_t\sim N(0,t)$ for all $t$.

I would like to compare this path with the one that I get using the Euler- Maruyama scheme:

\begin{equation*}
S(i+1) = S(i) + mu*S(i)*delta_t + sigma*S(i)*B_{t}
\end{equation*}

I would like to reproduce the graph at page 534 in the paper Higham (2001)"An algorithmic introduction to numerical simulation of SDE":
    [image]

I got a wrong result using the code:

```
rm(list=ls())
#Simulating  Geometric Brownian motion (GMB)
tau <- 1 #time to expiry
N <- 1000 #number of sub intervals
dt <- tau/N #length of each time sub interval
time <- seq(from=0, to=tau, by=dt) #time moments in which we simulate the process
length(time) #it should be N+1

mu <- 0.05 #GBM parameter 1
sigma <- 0.9 #GBM parameter 2
X0 <- 10 #initial condition

#simulate 1 Geometric Brownian motion path
Z <- rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1) #standard normal sample of N elements
dW <- Z*sqrt(dt) #Brownian motion increments
W <- c(0, cumsum(dW)) #Brownian motion at each time instant N+1 elements


#Analytic solution
X_analytic <- numeric(N+1) #vector of zeros, N+1 elements
X_analytic[1] <- X0 #first element of X_analytic is X0. with the for loop we find the other N elements

for(i in 2:length(X_analytic)){
  X_analytic[i] <- X_analytic[1]*exp(mu - 0.5*sigma^2*i*dt + sigma*W[i-1])
}

#plot X against time
plot(time, X_analytic, type = "l", main = "GBM path with analytical solution", 
     xlab = expression("t"[i]), ylab = expression("W"[t[i]]))


#Euler-Maruyama scheme
X_EM <- numeric(N+1) #vector of zeros, N+1 elements
X_EM[1] <- X0 #first element of X_EM is X0. with the for loop we find the other N elements

for(i in 2:length(X_EM)){
  X_EM[i] <- X_EM[i-1] + mu*X_EM[i-1]*dt + sigma*dW[i-1]
}

#plot X against time
plot(time, X_EM, type = "l", main = "GBM path with Euler-Maruyama scheme", 
     xlab = expression("t"[i]), ylab = expression("W"[t[i]]))

#plot W against time
matplot(time, cbind(X_analytic, X_EM), type = "l", main = "GBM", 
        xlab = expression("t"[i]), ylab = expression("X"[t[i]]))
```

This is the result:
           [image]

I don’t know which one is wrong and why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you do not plot one sample path but for each time point $t$, you simply plot one possible realisation of the random variable $S_t(\omega)$. Thus, you don't get a connected path.

(Just as a minor, you would need brackets in the exponential in your `for` loop, i.e.

```
X_analytic[i] <- X_analytic[1]*exp((mu - 0.5*sigma^2)*time[i] + sigma*Z[i-1]*sqrt(time[i]))
```

Nonetheless, in order to simulate a sample path of a geometric Brownian motion, note that
\begin{align*}
S_{t_i}=S_{t_{i-1}}\cdot\exp\left(\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(t_i-t_{i-1})+\sigma B_{t_i-t_{i-1}}\right)
\end{align*}
In your case, you chose a fixed step size $\Delta t=t_i-t_{i-1}$ for all $i$ such that
\begin{align*}
S_{t_i}=S_{t_{i-1}}\cdot\exp\left(\left(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)\Delta t+\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}Z\right),
\end{align*}
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Thus, change your `for` loop line to

```
X_analytic[i] <- X_analytic[i-1]*exp((mu - 0.5*sigma^2)*dt + sigma*Z[i-1]*sqrt(dt))
```

Furthermore, you may want to change the line `time <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=dt)` to `time <- seq(from=0, to=tau, by=dt)` such that you can actually make use of `tau`. Finally, the line `sigma <- 0.9` is a bit ambitious, a volatility of 90% is rather high. If you're modelling stock prices, a value of 0.1 to 0.4 is more appropriate.

---

### Edit in response to your updated code

You do not need the first `for` loop to compute the ``analytical'' solution. Simply use

```
X_analytic = X0 * exp((mu-0.5*sigma^2)*time+sigma*W)
```

Secondly, in your Euler approximation, you missed $S$ in the last term, so the `for` loop step should read as

```
X_EM[i] <- X_EM[i-1] + mu*X_EM[i-1]*dt + sigma*X_EM[i-1]*dW[i-1]
```

Comment: Why would you use the euler discretization when you know the analytical distribution?

Comment: @Andrew as I said in the answer, the approach above which is indeed a version of the Euler Maruyama algorithm, ensures that you can plot the sample path afterwards and it indeed looks like a geometric Brownian motion. The initial proposal leads to completely disconnected realisations of a geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: how would the code change for simulating multivariate *correlated* Brownian motion time series using Cholesky method, where some of the assets can be set correlated to one another

Comment: @develarist Sorry but I fail to see how this is related the OPs question in any way? There is only one single Brownian motion driving the process? One applies the Cholesky decomposition to the covariance matrix to generate sample paths of several correlated processes but this has nothing to do with the original question?

Comment: it's just an extension of the original question. if you don't know how, don't worry

Comment: @KeSchn, thank for your answer. My goal is to compare the Analytic solution vs the Euler Maruyama Discretization: the same plot that you see in the Higham paper “An algorithmic I ntroduction to numerical simulation of SDE”, page 534. In that graph they use the formula that I posted. How can I do the same graph?

Comment: @lucadibo Do you mean this questio? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49867/discretization-of-wiener-process   An alternative way to obtain a sample path of a geometric Brownian motion is to first obtain a sample path of $B_t$ and then compute $S_t$ as a function of $B_t$. Do you have any open questions to either this question here or perhaps about your previous question on Higham paper?

Comment: @develarist Cholesky is discussed in Glasserman's book on MC methods for Financial Engineering. I think it'd go beyond the scope of the comments to describe it in details but you can either ask a specific question here on Quant.SE or find many resources online?

Comment: @KeSchn the same paper, but different question. I’ll edit the original question give me 15 minutes. But I think that what I wanted to do is exactly simulate B and then compute S as function of B. I’ll edit the question in 15 minutes.

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look at Glasserman

Comment: @lucadibo No need to bother with editing the question. Do you know how to simulate $(B_t)$ as described in your last question? If so, then you can simply compute $S_t$ from $B_t$ by first scaling it with $\sigma$, then adding the time trend and finally taking the exponential. So, the key is a correct simulation of $(B_t)$...

Comment: @KeSchn yep but look at my results...It does not work! :( (I have edited the question and the code)

Comment: @Andrew I’ve edited the question: that’s the reason!

Comment: @lucadibo please see the updates to my answers, the first one is the step I described earlier: just plug the sample path of $(B_t)$ into the formula for $(S_t)$. The second addition is just a typo :)

Comment: Thanks really!!!!

Comment: @lucadibo No problem, my pleasure to help you. (: Please let me know if you have any other questions about simulating Brownian motion etc.

Comment: @KeSchn sure thanks, probably I'll get back to you for pricing barrier options with Monte Carlo during the week! I'm teaching a course at University about computational finance for the first time so I'm writing all the codes :)